# What font and size is used in Windows 7 File Explorer Tree

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I am having a hard time to find out which font is used by the Win 7 File Explorer in the tree view on the left hand side. Better, of course, would be if I can programmatically find out which the right font is (C#).

I searched the Windows 7 design guidelines but this particular scenario is not listed (at least I couldn't find it).

So anyone good with fonts?

Comment: Yeah, I tried Segoe UI 9pt but on my tree view the result doesn't look like the font of the Windows Explorer. I created a dummy treeview with Favorites and a child item Desktop to mimic the first two items of the explorer side bar and when I compare the two it sure looks different. The letter D for example is more compact. I also tried different sizes but no success.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the desktop and selecting Personalize yet?

Comment: Yes, all the objects with a font configured is Segoe UI 9 but it obviously is not in the Explorer Sidebar. When I change the Icon text font it also changes the sidebar font but when I set it to Segoe UI 9 it is a slightly differen, more compact font than Segoe UI 9. Fire up a demo win forms application and set this font on a tree view and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Your question asked about Win 7 File Explorer. That is not a demo win forms application. WinForms applications default to different fonts.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your latest comment. Please ignore my latest comment. The tree view control defaults to using the same font as icon titles, but applications can change it. WinForms applications do default to setting their forms to use different fonts than plain Win32 defaults. Now I guess you're saying that Win 7 File Explorer also tells its tree view to use a different font than plain Win32 defaults. If the user has an Explorer window open you can find the window and get its font, but if the user doesn't have one open, it seems difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All I want to know is what font and size is used by default in the Win7 File Explorer sidebar tree view.

It is NOT Segoe UI 9pt. It's a slightly different font - at least when I build a tree view with Segoe UI 9pt it looks different than the font used in Win7 File Explorer.

I do not really need to find that out programmatically. I just want to know which font/size that is because it is a bit more compact than the Segoe UI 9pt and want that font to be used as my default font.

Comment: Your original question asked how to find it out programmatically (C#). If you don't need it programmatically, then just open a Windows Explorer window and open Spy++ and maybe Spy++ will give you enough information to find the font -- for your machine only. Robert Harvey's avatar is a Chinese character which is displayed by Chinese Windows Explorer, using a font that Robert Harvey's answer didn't name, which you might not even have installed.

Comment: I did fire up Spy++ but couldn't find anything related to fonts. I guess I will give up as this seems to be much more difficult as I thought. Thanks anyway for your time and your comments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

P/Invoke to SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETICONTITLELOGFONT.

It depends on the language version of Windows. If you look at Robert Harvey's answer, you'll see a character that can't be displayed by Segoe UI.

Answer (score 16):

It's Segoe UI. In the future, you can use [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to resolve any questions you have about what font something is.

Comment: Nice link. I'm sure it will come in handy.

Comment: It did not detect standard fonts at windows dialogues and other programs. I tried to understand which font is used at almost the same systems but visually different fonts, for example, in Settings for USB Safely Remove - is it Segoe, Tahoma or what - it is totally failed asking me for every symbol what it is (and it is divided symbols for parts and I must connect them to one glyph - absolute fail).

Answer (score 7):

Actually it's probably `Segoe UI`.

If you right-click on the desktop and select Personalize from the menu that pops up, you should find a place in there that will tell you what the default window content font is.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html

Answer (score 4):

I took the liberty of capturing Windows Explorer with PAINT.NET (a great utility) and wrote the identical text above the captured text.  Here's what I can tell you.  The Font in Windows Explorer appears to be some compressed form of Seqoe UI.  There's simply no other font that's close enough.  However, it become apparent when you have a long word or phrase that the width has been compressed and the pixels bleed (aliasing).  I've not yet found out how to reproduce the exact spacing, but I'm pretty convinced of the following:

1. The font used by Windows Explorer is Segoe UI.
2. The point size is most likely 9.
3. The font is definitely compressed from what you would get using Seqoe UI 9.0.

Comment: On my en-us Windows 7, if I set Notepad to use Segoe UI Regular, 9 pt, I get the exact same text as Windows Explorer. If I use the same font in Word 2007, the spacing between words is slightly different.

Comment: I have noticed that even the slightest difference in size can have a noticeable impact on its appearance. You've probably already tried this, but have maybe the font size in File Explorer is `8.25` or `8.75`, or maybe even `9.25` or `9.75`? Seems a bit silly, but I have noticed that when I create new projects, the default font size is 9.75.

Answer (score 3):

It is not Segoe.  I've spent the last three days attempting to reverse engineer Windows Explorer in Windows 7.  Having worked with WPF and Vista, Segoe UI was my first choice for a font family, but I can confirm that it doesn't match up exactly with what Windows Explorer is using.

Comment: glad to hear that I am not alone (and not insane). If you find out more about the font, let us know...

Answer (score 2):

After working on this subject for several months, here's what I've concluded: The default font is in fact Segoe UI, 9 pt. (12 pixels).  However, there is something going on with the 'SnapsToDevicePixels' in Win32 that isn't or can't be emulated with WPF.  If you start to mess with the boundaries of your text in fractions, you can start to see some of the aliasing that goes on with fonts.  For example, place a simple canvas in front of your text block and give it a width of, say, 7.5 and you'll see your text start to 'bleed' into the surrounding pixels.  I've played around with every combination of fractional spacing and fractional fonts and still can't exactly reproduce the text we see with Windows Explorer.  This leaves me with the conclusion that Win32 text is simply rendered with a different engine than WPF.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Typography in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742190.aspx) topic, have you tried the [Font Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontstretch.aspx) property?

Answer (score 0):

That font is Tahoma 7,7pt - checked pixel-in-pixel in Photoshop, in Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Windows7 Aero or Windows7 Basic themes use Sagoe.
Windows7 "Windows Classic" theme uses Tahoma.

Answer (score 0):

The font is indeed Segoe UI, 9 pt.  However, the `Graphics.DrawString()` and `TextRenderer.DrawText()` methods render the font a little differently.  If you use `Graphics.DrawString()`, the text will appear to have more kerning than Windows uses.  `TextRenderer.DrawText()` appears to mimic the exact font that FileExplorer uses.